# Join lhs2TeX code blocks

Tags: lhs2tex

Consider a document that has multiple print versions. In one version a bit code is hidden (e.g. using `%if 0` or the `comment` package). In the other version there now are adjacent code `blocks` that really belong together.

```
%if elaborate
\begin{code}
more code
\end{code}
%endif
\begin{code}
the meat
\end{code}
```

In the brief version, `more code` is not shown and all is fine. In the elaborate version though, there are two adjacent `code` blocks that really should be one. By being intermittent, a vertical space corresponding to a paragraph is inserted.

How can I get rid of that space? One idea is to use a negative `\vspace` of a combination of `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip`, but none of the results I saw produced the correct spacing.